# Magento 2 Anti-CSRF Tokens/Form-Key For GraphQL

Tags: magento2, graphql, form-key, csrf-token

I need to validate a form-key / CSRF Token for a graphql mutation. Is there any way in Magento 2 to validate form-key or CSRF token for graphQl mutation.

We know default Magento2 controller  already have the fork-key validation functionality but I need to validate it for GraphQl mutation . Our site has Re-act front-end and we are using GraphQL for data management from back end. We need to implement CSRF protection into our React-js front-end. That is why I need to validate the fork-key in graphQl mutation.

Please suggests.

Thanks.